# Permission issue on HUE shared workflow job

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, oozie, hue

On cloudera HUE Created Workflow Job using user A, Job is shared to one group.

- User A can submit job.
- User B tries to submit job - permission error for workspace.
- Tried to give different path  `"/user/jadhavsa/fallout/workspace"` and also given +1777 permission.
- When job starts, job reset folder permission to owner and again same error

`Failed to create deployment directory: AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=josyula, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/jadhavsa/fallout/workspace":jadhavsa:places_unicorn_users:drwx--x--x (error 403)`

`AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=josyula, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/jadhavsa/fallout/workspace":jadhavsa:places_unicorn_users:drwx--x--x (error 403)`

Comment: I think you have not provided the correct permissions. `hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /user/jadhavsa/fallout/workspace`.

Comment: I tried 777 as well - not working

Comment: Check user access in the Hue groups (Using Hue UI)

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that User don't have rights. Make both user as root user and give 777 permission to that folder .